# Eliminate the leading '1' in front of US phone numbers in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of US phone numbers, some of which have a leading "1" at the start of the phone number. If the number is 11 digits long, that means the first digit is the "1" I want to get rid of (at least within my data set).

```
phone <- c("1234567890", "1234567890", "5556456890", "5444567890", "19729772976")
```

I stripped all whitespace, punctuation, and dashes using

```
gsub("[- .)(+]|[a-zA-Z]*:?","", phone)
```

I am unsure how to code it to remove the first digit if the string is 11 characters long. Or in other words, remove the first character in a vector if the string is a certain length.

Comment: Using `stringr`: `ifelse(str_length(phone) == 11, str_remove(phone, "^1"), phone)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sub` from `base R` to match the `1` at the start (`^`) of the string, and capture the 10 digits (`\\d{10}`) as a group (`(...)`) till the end (`$`) of the string, and specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group in replacement.  This will prevent losing any 1 that are in the 10 digit strings

```
sub("^1(\\d{10})$", "\\1", phone)
```

-output

```
[1] "1234567890" "1234567890" "5556456890" "5444567890" "9729772976"
```